# Getting value of Date Time Picker and using BETWEEN for filtering date in Ms Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have a From and To `DateTimePicker`. I converted them into a `String` and use it to filter a `MsAccess database` of a specific range but there is a problem with the filtering. For example, I would like to filter from January 1, 2015 to January 31, 2015. The results include Januaries from previous years. What seems to be the problem with my statement?

This is my code:

```
Dim connectionstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\STSlog.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
Dim command As New OleDbCommand
Dim commstring As String
Dim fromdatestring As String = FromDPicker.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim todatestring As String = ToDPicker.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

commstring = "SELECT Mark, ProjectCode, Project, Activity, today, Regular, OT FROM data WHERE today BETWEEN '" & fromdatestring & "' AND '" & todatestring & "' AND  empno = '" & TimeSheetAdmin.EmpNumCmbBox.SelectedItem.ToString & "' ORDER BY VAL(Mark) DESC"
command = New OleDbCommand(commstring, conn)
```

Comment: Why convert the datetimes to string?  That's just silly.  Use a parameterized query and then you won't have to worry about it.  Plus you will eliminate the sql injection security vulnerability that you have.

Comment: The date field in my database is a Short Text type of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```sql
..."WHERE today BETWEEN '" & fromdatestring & "' AND '" & todatestring & "'"...
```

To

```
..."WHERE today >= #" & fromdatestring & "# AND today <= #" & todatestring & "#"...
```

Please note that MS-Access uses #-Delimiters for `Date`-Values (afaik), this could also be a problem in your query.

Comment: Does this work even if the column is a Short Text type and not Date Time?

Comment: I don't think so, but it actually depends on the way you format your dates. `20150731` for `31st July 2015` might work, as 20.150.731 is a greater number than `20150323` for `23rd March 2015`. But I would strongly recommend to change the DataType of your column to `Date`, as the different DataTypes exist for reasons as Aaron Bertrand stated in [this well written post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: Your code is working. I changed the data type to Date. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask one more thing since were on the topic? The years are fine but the from date is having a bug that doesnt include the date of the date time picker for example I select January 1, it displays January 2 onwards. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please check if you selecting `>=` (greater or same) instead of just `>` (only greater) so the starting date itself will be included. You could also try to select all `Date`-Values from 01/01/2015 00:00 (including a time-value to start your SELECT from).

Comment: My statement has >= in it and <= for the 'to' date

Comment: Set a BreakPoint at the `command = New OleDbCommand(commstring, conn)` line and check the fully build query (the value of `commstring`) . Does `fromdatestring` has the correct value of `01/01/2015`? What happens if you try to run your programmatically build query-string manually on your access database by creating a new query **inside** the access database?